# MongoDB log authentication name use default name system

Tags: linux, database, mongodb, logging, microservices

We use MongoDB v4.4.2 in prod and 4 test servers with the same version of db.

4 test servers have the same log information about access. For example information from test:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-09T15:13:28.106+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20250,   "ctx":"conn3694","msg":"Successful authentication","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-1","principalName":"myUserName","authenticationDatabase":"myDbName","client":"my mircoservice Ip"}}
```

But in prod gets log with unknown information about name and other, example from prod:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-09T16:13:54.837+06:00"},"s":"I", "c":"ACCESS", "id":20250, "ctx":"conn4388","msg":"Successful authentication","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","principalName":"__system","authenticationDatabase":"local","client":"DatabaseIP"}}
```

Question: Why in prod we got information like local "principalName":"__system","authenticationDatabase":"local", in test full microservice address and user name information

Database version and other information the same, one big difference is prod has replica, test doesn't have.

Do we need to change some settings from prod? If yes, which configuration? How can I find difference between test and prod?

Comment: User `__system` is the internal user used from other nodes in the replica set. This line is not showing **your** connection.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit for test I get full address, but in prod it shows like internal address. Maybe it is because test doesn't have replica, but prod has? And prod gets all data from replica and thinks it is internal address?

Comment: The `__system` user is the user which are used to connect replica set to each other. Of course, it does not exist on a stand-alone inistance.